# Loading fonts with the help of hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fonts

I am working on a project where I supply users with a selection of various free to use fonts.
Loading these fonts seems tricky. Simply loading them by supplying the necessary @font-face declarations is not enough, as the fonts do naturally not get loaded, unless an element on the website actually uses one of these fonts.

So I went over to creating two dozen (or more) "hidden"  elements off the screen (body { overflow:hidden }), each using one of the custom fonts. This forces all browsers to actually render the font, thus loading it properly.

My question is, if this technique is "okay" to use (I have read about various scenarios, when this was used) and whether there is a more elegant solution.

What I have tried so far:

Getting font files through jQuery's .ajax() and .get() functions.
Using the vanilla XMLHttpRequest() method.
Making use of the $(window).load event.

Thanks a lot for any input!

Comment: How many fonts are you trying to load at the same time? Number and total file size?

Comment: You're pushing several potentially large downloads onto users at once, which can be burdensome. Also, I'm not clear why you want users to download a font if they can't see it in use anywhere.

Comment: Users can click on a button to create a <div> element, which uses a font, specified by the selection in a <select> element. This <select> has all possible fonts listed (possibly 30-40 fonts). Dynamically creating the div with a selected font that has not been rendered yet, causes the <div> to appear in a default system font instead. That is why I want to render them beforehand.

Comment: @LaughDonor the number of files varies from 4 to 24 per font-face (some only have regular weight, others appear in light and bold as well, plus italic versions). The file sizes thus vary between 100kb and 300kb for 4 files and about 500-1.200kb for 24 font-files. But browsers do not load everything. Chrome limits the download to the .woff files only, for example. So realistically the dl per font is between 15kb and 115kb so far for the largest font-file-batch.